# Adding X-Robots-Tag header to a location with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers, nginx-config, x-robots-tag

I have a wordpress website running on a server with apache with a nginx as proxy in front of it.

The site has a plugin which displays the telegram channel in an widget as a iframe, i want to exclude results from this iframe in google search results.

I have tried to add this configuration to nginx.
 `location ~ /wptelegram { add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet"; }`

The problem is, now the iframe shows the start page, not the actual telegram widget content.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by repeating the proxy config from the proxy location to this location.

```
location ~ /wptelegram {
    add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet";
    proxy_pass https://111.111.111.111:7081;
    proxy_hide_header upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    access_log off;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    proxy_no_cache $no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization $arg_nocache;
    proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization $arg_nocache;
    proxy_cache example.com_proxy;
    proxy_cache_valid "5";
    proxy_cache_use_stale http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 updating;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try allowing everything, except iframes and adjust the selector based in you iframe Id

```
location ~ /wptelegram {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
  if ($http_user_agent ~* (Baidubot|Googlebot|Bingbot)) {
    # blok crawler for iframes only
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /block.html break;
  }
}
```